# How to time events

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

What is the best practice behind handling timed events in `C`? The scenario I'm looking at is that i need to resend data to the server from the client if i do not receive a response from the server within a second.

Code would be nice, but explanation of the concept would be far more valuable.

Comment: Your post is tagged with [tag:tcp]. TCP does this for you.

Comment: meager is correct, TCP will automatically check for success and re-send any data that was not recieved

Comment: Of course TCP's re-send is only going to help if the reason for the non-response was a dropped network packet.  If the server didn't respond for some other reason (e.g. because it's buggy or uncooperative) then a manual resend might be necessary.  (Of course in that case a better fix would be to debug the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operating systems have some form of timer. In Linux/Unix/Posix you have [`alarm`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm), and in windows there's [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, basiclaly, you send a message off, and set a timer to a time when you expect to have got a reply - 1s, 10s, 30s - whatever makes senses for your circumstances.

If you get a reply, you cancel the timer, and do whatever else you plan to do with the reply. If no reply arrives before the timer fires, you send again [it may mean "signal some semaphore or flag" to send again, rather than actually doing that in the handler for the timer].

For other operating systems, you'll have to tell us what you are looking at, but most have some sort of mechanism to handle "tell me when X time has passed".

Answer (score 0):

This requires a prior synchronization between client and server. Also, you must have a library for event management. Such of libraries are mentioned in [timer and I/O Event Manager library](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/event.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your program is using non-blocking I/O and doing its blocking inside of select() or poll(), these functions have an optional timeout argument that lets you specify that the select()/poll() call should return after a certain amount of time has elapsed, even if no I/O events have occurred.  You can use that functionality to get your program to perform an action at intervals.